# How long do peers normally stay connected?

Tags: network, protocol, peers

I've been experimenting with the Bitcoin protocol by trying to connect to peers and receive blocks, which has been working so far. However, often peers will close the TCP connection within a couple of minutes of connection, despite me sending pings periodically.

My question is, is there something else in the protocol that would result in a peer closing the connection quickly? Do peers expect messages other than `version`, `verack` and `ping`? (My code introduces itself as implementing protocol version 70011 and offering network services.)

I have tried looking through the reference client code to figure out what might cause this, but admittedly I'm not sure where to start.